# Laravel 5.6 - 403 forbidden on server

Tags: php, http-status-code-403, laravel-5.6

My project works fine in local. When I upload it to my Debian 8 server, I face an error like:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I searched about my issue and find out two questions, [Laravel - Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18272557/3534952) and [Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10873295/3534952). I tested every solution that they suggested as answers but, not worked in my case.

Here is a list of what I did:

- Testing many permissions for project folder such as 777, 775 or 755 by this command: `chmod -R 777 /path/to/my/project/`
- Adding a new `.htaccess` to the project root and putting this codes in it:

  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>`
- Change `server.php` to `index.php` and move `/public/.htaccess` to root of the project.

Is there any solution?!

Comment: The Apache server deny all OPTIONS request and this is what cause this error