# WooCommerce REST API : automattic/woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using this automattic/woocommerce, A PHP wrapper for the WooCommerce REST API.

It's working fine from my local development environment and a cloud development environment but it's getting errors when applied to LIVE environment. I got errors like "Method Not Allowed", "Forbidden", "Don't have permission to access".

Tried using an empty wordpress with no plugins and a fresh .htaccess but still getting these errors.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server) solution worked for me. Also make sure you have proper permissions. e-g storage and bootstrap folder.