# Forbidden to access Laravel folder

Tags: laravel

I created a new blog

```
Laravel new blog
```

I changed DocumentRoot to point at the public folder

```
DocumentRoot /home/XXXX/blog/public
```

I added a .htaccess file as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I added the file to both blog and public folders

But I still get:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at XX.XXX.167.3X Port 80
```

As I have installed in a user folder, do I somehow need to set the user of the apache2 engine?  A bit lost here, any help appreciated.

Comment: Ttry to set 755 permission recursively in `/home/XXXX/blog`

Comment: Have you tried the other solutions from you reference link

Comment: Change owner of `/home/XXXX/blog` to be `www-data`.

Comment: If you go to that url (server_ip/public/index.php), what does it tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

permission issue the fix was try this the first solution

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R directory-name
```

alternative you can create and put this .htaccess file in your laravel installation folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I set DocumentRoot to the new directory and changed the permission, it worked!

Comment: I am happy that it was helpful for you!