# Laravel Apache24 on Windows 10 -> 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, windows, laravel, apache

I want to create a more realistic dev environment for my laravel app. 
I want to start my laravel app with apache.

The issue is, I always get this error if I try to access the project through the URL (localhost.eu):

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

What I have done so far:

1. Edited the `httpd.conf` in `Apache\conf`, I uncommented this line:

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

2. Edited the `httpd-vhosts.conf` in `Apache\conf\extra`, I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Y:/PHP-Projects"
    ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "Y:/PHP-Projects/Project-Admin-PHP/public"
    ServerName localhost.eu 
    <Directory Y:/PHP-Projects/Project-Admin-PHP/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Edited the `hosts` file in `Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, I added:

`127.0.0.1 www.localhost.eu localhost.eu`

4. I also tried to edit the default laravel `.htaccess`, basically I tried all solutions in [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)
5. Edited the `httpd.conf` in `Apache\conf`:

```
<Directory Y:/PHP-Projects/Project-Admin-PHP/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It was:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

After every step I restarted the apache24 service.

NOTE: If I try to access, f.e. `localhost.eu/robots.txt` **I see the file**, so it correctly connected to the project folder.

If I type in `http://localhost.eu/index.php` **I see the code of the index.php**, it is somehow not executed?

Comment: P.S.: In step 5 I edited the Directory argument in the httpd.conf file, dont do this. Also you will need to add this `DirectoryIndex index.php` in `httpd-vhosts.conf` in the `Directory` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, you forgot enable php module. In httpd.conf uncomment enabling php extension. I recomend you installing all in one web server package like wamp http://www.wampserver.com/en/ or xamp. They solve all these problems related with configuring web server.

Add this to your `httpd.conf` file of apache:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
LoadModule php7_module "C:/PHP7/php7apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP7"
```

Comment: Sadly there is no enabling php extension var in the httpd.conf file. I know that there is XAMP, but I discovered it too late. I have already setup everything myself and I'd like to finish this and understand whats going on. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Probably something is wrong in the php.ini, I use php 7.

Comment: You can't find line like that `LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/php5apache2_4.dll"` in httpd.conf file

Comment: Thats the weird issue, I have no LoadModule php at all in my apache httpd.conf. Also why php5_module? I use PHP7

Comment: I found this file in my PHP folder: `php7apache2_4.dll` what now?

Comment: try to add this line in your httpd.conf file `LoadModule php7_module  "C://path_to_php_folder/php7apache2_4.dll"`

Comment: Yeah I fixed it. Thanks for the help. May I edit your question with the relevant code and accept it?

Comment: Ok. I glad help you