# You don't have permission to access / on this server in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

i have set .htaccess in laravel root repo and set full permission for root folder

but can't work it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

i have set abow .htaccess code but it's not working

Comment: Have you tried @amd comment.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: Did you try to restart the apache server? How about your virtual host?

Comment: I have shared hosting server and i have no access to restart apache

Comment: @dilip i have tried

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server