# Laravel gives forbidden 403 error while submitting <a> tag from summernote editor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, summernote

I tried to use several stackoverflow answers but didn't work

[Laravel - Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)
is one of them

When I copy content from webpage which is having hperlink
it gives me this error

[image]

How I can solve it?

Comment: Perhaps there is validation in place to prevent that?

Comment: no there is something wrong on server side. it is working fine on local server

Comment: Do you have code view enabled on summernote? After pasting the content from another page, you might want to check code view first for anything odd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)